Topology on the space of test functions and its metrizability
Does there exist a complete metric on the space of smooth functions with compact support, $ C^\infty_c(\Omega)$?
If so, what is its definition and what properties ensure its completeness?
Additionally, if such a metric exists, why do we prefer the inductive limit topology over the metric topology in analysis?
Thanks for your help!

Not sure if there is an interesting metric but I think we prefer the TVS structure over the metric space structure in general

Yes, there exists a complete metric on $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, since as sets $\mathbb{R} \cong C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and there is a complete metric on $\mathbb{R}$. But this metric has a priori no connection to the vector space structure of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, so is useless in functional analysis. Maybe there is also an isomorphism of abstract vector spaces $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega) \to C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Then there would also be a Frechet vector space structure on $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$.
We want a complete metric that induces a TVS structure on $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

@psl2Z Thanks for your comment. I have a doubt, can a metric topology be complete on the space of test functions? Won't it violate Baire category theorem?

I don't think so because then $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ would be isometric to $\mathbb{R}$ (or $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ if the abstract vector spaces $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ are isomorphic; I don't know if this is true)? But this metric ignores all other properties of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and is therefore useless to study the space $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

$C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ has a Hamel basis of the candinality of the continuum so that there are linear bijections with every separable Banach space. One can thus make $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ even a Banach space. However, this Banach space structure has nothing to with the differentiability of the elements of  $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. There is no contradiction to Baire's theorem because the subspace of test functions with fixed compact support is not closed.

@Jochen Thanks for your comment. Could you please explicitely mention the metric or give a reference, which makes $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ complete, for $\Omega$ open and $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ in particular

This Banach space structur is by no means explicit (there is no constructive way to produce a Hamel basis). Anyway, if $T:C_c^\infty(\Omega)\to \ell^2$ is a linear bijection you can just define $|f|=|T(f)|_{\ell^2}$. This makes $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ even a Hilbert space.

This question would be much clearer if you explicitly stated (or even better, defined) the topology you want this metric to induce.
